# Image not showing in Blog made using Jekyll in github

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have made a blog using github page but the image is not loading.I have tried all things but I am still stuck with it.
The link to my github code is [here](https://github.com/shivank01/hcz-jekyll-blog)

The problem is in the file  _posts/2017-04-02-Kronothon.md  and the image is in  /assets/Kronothon1.png .

Please help me out with this.
You can see the blog post [here](https://shivank01.github.io/hcz-jekyll-blog//hackathon/2017/04/02/Kronothon.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**\config.yml**

```
baseurl: "/hcz-jekyll-blog"
url: "https://shivank01.github.io"
```

**Calling your pictures** (as noted by Subash Chandra Manohari)

```
![Pic1]({{ "/assets/Kronothon1.png" | absolute_url }})
```

and not

```
![Pic1]({{ " /assets/Kronothon1.png " | absolute_url }})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration setting is **wrong!**:

```
baseurl: "https://shivank01.github.io/"
url: ""
```

Instead, remove `baseurl` entirely and set `url` as the site's landing:

```
# baseurl: "" (commented out)
url: "https://shivank01.github.io"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `https://shivank01.github.io/assets/Kronothon1.png` instead of `/https://shivank01.github.io/%20/assets/Kronothon1.png`. There was a problem in the image url. Check it out in config.yml file. Hope this helps :)